# Dynamic append DIV and calculate data inside the div using class name in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a `div` to add the input field using the class name and display the value, and also create a button to add more field that has the same class as above, but only the first `field` can be used to add the input, I know how I tried is incorrect. I don't want to use ID, increase ID or related to ID. It may be better to increase the `class name` also but is there any way to keep the same class name and function working. Thanks in advance

**Edited:**  My question part and my snippet part is not same for better understanding.

```js
function addMoreSchedule8WDV() {
  // alert('yeah');
  $("#sch8_wdv").append('<div style="border-style: dotted; border-radius: 10px; border-width: thin; margin-top: 10px;">' +
    '<div class="col-md-12">' +
    '<div class="row">' +
    '<div class="col-md-2">' +
    '<label for="assetName">Name</label><br>' +
    '<input type="text" id="assetName" class="form-control">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-2">' +
    '<label for="assetDOP">DOP</label><br>' +
    '<input type="date" id="assetDOP" class="form-control date_of_purchase">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-2">' +
    '<label for="assetOC">OC</label><br>' +
    '<input type="number" min="0" id="assetOC" class="form-control originalCost">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-2">' +
    '<label for="assetWDV">WDV</label><br>' +
    '<input type="number" min="0" id="assetWDV" class="form-control assWDV">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-2">' +
    '<label for="assetADD">ADD</label><br>' +
    '<input type="number" min="0" id="assetADD" class="form-control addition">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-2">' +
    '<label for="assetEUL">EUL</label><br>' +
    '<input type="number" min="0" id="assetEUL" class="form-control no_of_year">' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="col-md-12" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">' +
    '<div class="row">' +
    '<div class="col-md-2">' +
    '<label for="assetBDA">BDA</label><br>' +
    '<input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetBDA" class="form-control bdaValue">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-2">' +
    '<label for="assetDays">Day Used</label><br>' +
    '<input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetDays" class="form-control dayUsed">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-2">' +
    '<label for="assetRateofDep">Rate of Dep.</label><br>' +
    '<input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetRateofDep" class="form-control rateOfDep">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-2">' +
    '<label for="assetDepAmount">Dep. Amount</label><br>' +
    '<input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetDepAmount" class="form-control depAmount">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-2">' +
    '<label for="assetNetBlock">Net Block</label><br>' +
    '<input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetNetBlock" class="form-control netBlock">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-2">' +
    '<label for="removeWDV">Remove</label><br>' +
    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="width: 100%; padding-left: 5px;" class="btn btn-outline-warning removeSch8">Remove Content</a>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>');
  $("#sch8_wdv").on("click", ".removeSch8", function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
  });
}

// trigger for Fixed Assets WDV
$(document).on('change', '#yearEnd, .date_of_purchase, .no_of_year, .addition, .originalCost, .assWDV', function() {
  calculateWDVFixedAssets();
});
// end triggered

function calculateWDVFixedAssets() {
  var current_year_input = $("#yearEnd").val()
  var current_year = new Date(current_year_input + '-03-31');
  var last_year = current_year_input - 1;
  var last_year_correct = new Date(last_year + '-04-01');
  var date_of_purchase = new Date($(".date_of_purchase").val());
  var no_of_year = $('.no_of_year').val();
  var original_cost = $('.originalCost').val();
  var addition = $('.addition').val();
  var wdv = $('.assWDV').val();
  var bda, dayUsed;
  if (last_year_correct < date_of_purchase) {
    $(".originalCost").prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $(".originalCost").prop('disabled', false);
  }

  // below code is for calculate Day Used
  if (date_of_purchase != '') {
    if (date_of_purchase < last_year_correct) {
      dayUsed = 365;
      $(".dayUsed").val(dayUsed);
    } else if (date_of_purchase > last_year_correct && date_of_purchase < current_year) {
      dayUsed = Math.round(Math.abs((current_year.getTime() - date_of_purchase.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
      $(".dayUsed").val(dayUsed);
    } else {
      $(".dayUsed").val('');
      $(".originalCost").val('');
      console.log('error');
    }
  }

  // below is for calculate BDA
  if (no_of_year != '') {
    if (date_of_purchase > last_year_correct && date_of_purchase < current_year) {
      bda = (no_of_year * 365);
      $(".bdaValue").val(bda);
    } else if (date_of_purchase < last_year_correct) {
      var bda2 = (no_of_year * 365);
      var year_minus = Math.round(Math.abs((last_year_correct.getTime() - date_of_purchase.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
      var total = (+bda2 - +year_minus);
      $('.bdaValue').val(total + 1);
    } else {
      $(".originalCost").val('');
      console.log('error');
    }
  }

  // rate of depreciation
  if (original_cost != '' || addition != '' || wdv != '') {
    var bdaPass = $('.bdaValue').val();
    var s = ((+original_cost + +addition) * (5 / 100));
    var c = (+wdv + +addition);
    var n = (bdaPass / 365);
    var xy = (s / c);
    var yz = (1 / n);
    var power = Math.pow(xy, yz);
    var power_new = parseFloat(power.toFixed(2));
    var new_total = (1 - +power) * 100;
    $('.rateOfDep').val(parseFloat(new_total.toFixed(4)));


    // rate of depreciation
    var rate_of_dep = $('.rateOfDep').val();
    var f_rod = ((+wdv + +addition) * (rate_of_dep / 100));
    var day_used_rod = $(".dayUsed").val();
    var s_rod = (day_used_rod / 365);
    var total_rod = (f_rod * s_rod);
    var round_total = Math.round(total_rod);
    $('.depAmount').val(round_total);


    // net block
    var f_netBlock = (+wdv + +addition);
    var dep_net = $('.depAmount').val();
    var net_block = (+f_netBlock - +dep_net);
    $('.netBlock').val(parseFloat(net_block.toFixed(2)));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p> Try inserting Year Ended = 2018, Name = Test, DOP = 1st April, 2010, OC = 1250000, wdv = 686931, add = null(no need to enter), eul = 15 then it will give the output bda=2919, day used = 365, rate of dep = 25.8986, dep amt = 177906, net block = 509025..</p>

<p>Ignore the console error</p>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="yearEnd">Year Ended in</label>
  <input type="number" min="0" name="yearEnded" id="yearEnd" class="form-control" placeholder="Eg:- 2001" required>
</div>

<div style="border-style: dotted; border-radius: 10px; border-width: thin;">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="assetName">Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="assetName" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="assetDOP">DOP</label><br>
        <input type="date" id="assetDOP" class="form-control date_of_purchase">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="assetOC">OC</label><br>
        <input type="number" min="0" id="assetOC" class="form-control originalCost">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="assetWDV">WDV</label><br>
        <input type="number" min="0" id="assetWDV" class="form-control assWDV">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="assetADD">ADD</label><br>
        <input type="number" min="0" id="assetADD" class="form-control addition">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="assetEUL">EUL</label><br>
        <input type="number" min="0" id="assetEUL" class="form-control no_of_year">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="assetBDA">BDA</label><br>
        <input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetBDA" class="form-control bdaValue">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="assetDays">Day Used</label><br>
        <input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetDays" class="form-control dayUsed">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="assetRateofDep">Rate of Dep.</label><br>
        <input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetRateofDep" class="form-control rateOfDep">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="assetDepAmount">Dep. Amount</label><br>
        <input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetDepAmount" class="form-control depAmount">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="assetNetBlock">Net Block</label><br>
        <input type="number" readonly min="0" id="assetNetBlock" class="form-control netBlock">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="sch8_wdv"></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" style=" margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px!important;" onclick="addMoreSchedule8WDV()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add More</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/fdsqozmv/27/)**.

You could attach the `input` event to both inputs at the same time as:

```js
$(document).on('input', '.first_no, .second_no', function() {
  var parent    = $(this).parent();

  var first_no  = parent.find('.first_no').val();
  var second_no = parent.find('.second_no').val();
  var total     = parent.find('.total');

  if (!isNaN(first_no) && !isNaN(second_no)) {
    total.val(+first_no + +second_no);
  }
});

function addMoreField() {
  $('#expanded').append(
    '<div><br>' +
    '<input type="number" class="first_no">' +
    ' plus ' +
    '<input type="number" class="second_no">' +
    ' is equal ' +
    '<input type="number" class="total">' +
    '</div>'
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="number" class="first_no"> plus
  <input type="number" class="second_no"> is equal
  <input type="number" class="total">
</div>

<div id="expanded"></div>
<br>
<button onclick="addMoreField()">Add More</button>
```

Comment: Hi Zakaria Acharki, this answer is good and perfect, but it is a little bit hard for what I am really trying to achieve in my project, the logic is same but when I used parent.fin() it redirects me to the else condition only...

Comment: Hi brother, try to describe more what is the problem and i'm ready to help

Comment: ok, I'll edit my snippet like what I'm doing in my project, please check the updated question.

Comment: Yes sure, I'll check it

Comment: Check with me this example https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/fdsqozmv/15/ , I have removed all the id's but I can't really get the logic of `calculateWDVFixedAssets()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179804/discussion-between-vpa-and-zakaria-acharki).

Comment: Instead of this function `addMoreField`, you can actually clone the existing dom items to create new elements.

Comment: Yes, that possible @Piccaza but then you need to loop through all the elements inside and empty the value then to check which one should be disabled by default and "enable/disable" ...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var addFields = function() {
  var container = $(".dynamic-section");
  var newFields = $(".row:first").clone();
  $(newFields).find("input").val("");
  container.append(newFields);
};

var add = function(num1, num2) {
  num1 = (num1.length > 0 && !isNaN(num1)) ? parseInt(num1) : 0;
  num2 = (num2.length > 0 && !isNaN(num2)) ? parseInt(num2) : 0;
  return num1 + num2;
}

$(document).on("keyup", ".first,.second", function(e) {
  var currentRow = $(e.target.parentElement);
  var first = currentRow.find(".first").val();
  var second = currentRow.find(".second").val();
  var result = currentRow.find(".result");
  result.val(add(first, second));
});
```

```css
    body {
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .row {
      padding: 10px 0px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row" >
  <input type="number" class="first"  placeholder="first"/> +
  <input type="number" class="second" placeholder="second"/> =
  <input type="number" class="result" placeholder="result"/>
</div>

<div class="dynamic-section"></div>

<button type="button" name="addFields" onclick="addFields()">Add fields</button>
```

Comment: Why you're mixing vanillaJS with jQuery?

Comment: thank you so much, it works. but can u recheck my snippet cause i edited

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Its all pure js and jQuery.

Comment: Yes why the mixing both pure and jQuery ?

Comment: Didn't do it intentionally, happened as I am comforted with few functions in JS and few functions in jQuery. Will update answer to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Made a bit shorter version.

```js
$(document).on('input', '.a, .b, .c', function() {
   var i = $(this).parent().find('input');
   i[2].value = parseInt(i[0].value) + parseInt(i[1].value);
});

$('#add').on('click', function() {
    $('.main').append('\
     <div class="computation">\
            <input type="number" class="a"> + \
            <input type="number" class="b"> = \
            <input type="number" class="c">\
        </div>\
    ');
});
```

```css
.computation {
    padding: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

button {
    margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="computation">
        <input type="number" class="a"> +
        <input type="number" class="b"> =
        <input type="number" class="c">
    </div>
</div>

<button id="add">Add more</button>
```

Comment: thank you so much, can u recheck my snippet, cause i've made changed